# Why creation of custom Exceptions needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, the question is in the title.
The only one thought that comes in mind why we need to introduce custom Exception class is to pass additional info with exception raising.
Any additional reasons?

Comment: This is not Ruby, much less Rails specific and should've probably be better asked in http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you may want to create custom exceptions:

- Add custom logic to an exception, to simplify the interaction with the exception itself. [`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L13-L27) is an example: the message is built from the actual record errors, and a reference to the record itself is stored in the exception.
- Differentiate errors to improve error handling. Having different error types allows you to specifically rescue only certain types of errors, and not all the errors. You can also have different rescue blocks depending on the error type.
- Re-raising typed errors. This is very important for libraries that internally relies on other libraries. A good practice of software composition is that library A uses B internally, whatever error B raises should be wrapped into an A error to make sure that the users of A don't have to deal with B directly.

In general, providing custom errors enhances the error handling experience. A good resource to learn more about errors is Avdi's book [Exceptional Ruby](http://exceptionalruby.com/). Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the Pokemon exception handling (*Gotta' catch them all*) anti-pattern it is better to raise your own exception types.

When using a library for example you should get meaningful error types - for example `AuthorizationError` or `TimeOutError` - it lets programmers deal with exceptions by type instead of matching the error message or adding a clunky system of numeric codes which does not really belong in an object oriented language.